# Does an iOS app with backgrounding support get terminated upon application update?

Tags: ios, plist

Basically my application has some configuration plist files that get read only when some configuration singletons get instantiated.

In the app update, I might update that plist and want it to be re-read as if the application had been terminated so that the singletons get recreated again and the plist files get re-read.

If iOS somehow updates the backgrounded/suspended app (and does a resume when the app gets launched again) that would both a) seem strange and b) necessitate that I add some code to explicitly re-read my configuration plists upon resume, or, better yet, upon application update.

Comment: Is there a question as a part of this?

Comment: Yes, see the headline ("Does an iOS app with backgrounding support get terminated upon application update?")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is terminated (even if its currently executing a scheduled background task), then the app data gets updated and when the users decides to tap your apps icon again, the normal app cycle begins with `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could try to partially validate this by updating my application in XCode, although it might not be the same as an app store update.

Comment: If you have an app with an pending update which you know executes something in the background, you can launch it and then install the update. Then check the crashlogs in Xcode and verify it this way ;)